# Getting PHP warnings while running php -v on CLI

Tags: php, sphinx, eaccelerator

Getting below errors while running php -v on my server, it was running fine since many days and suddenly showing up this:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   './/usr/local/sphinx/sphinx.so' - .//usr/local/sphinx/sphinx.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   './/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/eaccelerator.so'
>   - .//usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/eaccelerator.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Apr  2 2012 18:43:50) Copyright (c) 1997-2010
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend
>   Technologies with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.14, Copyright (c)
>   2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd.

Comment: You're including PHP extensions that don't exist. [Stop](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+Startup%3A+Unable+to+load+dynamic+library).

Comment: yeah... disabling sphinx and eaccelerator fixed the issue.